# Sobre carga de imagenes BufferedImage en java

Tags: java, imagen, código-de-barras

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en java en el el cual se llena un formulario y los datos ingresados se pasan a códigos de barras. Ya descargue la libreria jbarcodebean, ya generé el primer campo como código de barras.

Lo que quiero saber es, **¿Cómo agregarle los demás campos de código de barras a esa misma imagen?**

Esto es lo que tengo para procesar el codigo de barras de los campos.

```
JBarcodeBean barcode = new JBarcodeBean();
//nuestro tipo de codigo de barras
barcode.setCodeType(new Interleaved25());
//valor a codificar
barcode.setCode(name);
barcode.setCheckDigit(true);
barcode.setCode(phone);
barcode.setCheckDigit(true);
BufferedImage img;
img = barcode.draw(
        new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
//guardar en disco como png
File file = new File("codebar.png");
try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Formulario_1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: este es el codigo que tengo para procesar los campos a codigo de barras.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estas haciendo en el codigo es setear codigos para tu codigo de barra, pero siempre lo reemplazas por el ultimo.

```
barcode.setCode(name);
barcode.setCheckDigit(true);
barcode.setCode(phone);
barcode.setCheckDigit(true);
```

En este caso quedare como codigo de barras `phone`, deberia ser asi :

```
barcode.setCode(name + phone);
```

Y cambiar el tipo de `CodeType` que das, ya que al parecer `new Interleaved25` acepta solo numeros, puedes cambiarlo por `new Code39`

```
JBarcodeBean barcode = new JBarcodeBean();
//nuestro tipo de codigo de barras
barcode.setCodeType(new Code39());
//valor a codificar
String name = "Nicolas";
String phone = "33434";
barcode.setCode(name + " - " + phone);
barcode.setCheckDigit(true);
BufferedImage img;
img = barcode.draw(
    new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
//guardar en disco como png
File file = new File("codebar.png");
try {
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("error : " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

[Code39](http://jbarcodebean.sourceforge.net/barcodes/code39.html)

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte!!! voy a porbarlo para ver como funciona

Comment: Muy bien! Cualquier cosa me comentas!

Comment: Si te ayudo mi respuesta recuerda marcarla como correcta @SocraskySalamanca

Comment: Fijate que ya lo probe pero, lo que necesito es que el campo nombre se imprima con su codigo de barras, el de apellido con su propio codigo de barras, el de phone con su propio codigo de barras y asi respectivamente. En el codigo que me recomiendas imprime en un solo codigo de barras toda esa informacion y yo la necesito separada un codigo de barras para cada campo.

Comment: Tienes que hacer 1 por uno entonces. Recuerd aue esa funcion solo dibuja 1

Comment: exacto uno por uno. Estoy leyendo una documetacion de un cuate que dibuja los codigos de barras con la libreria javabar para ver como los puedo generar.